# VBA, Looping through multiple files, copy/paste to last row

Tags: vba, excel

I have my code which uses a picker and I choose which csv files I want to gather data from and paste to my master workbook. However the data just replaces itself in column B of my master workbook. I know I have to use .End(xlUp) or .End(xlDown), not sure where to put this.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsMaster As Workbook, csvFiles As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim File As Integer
Dim r As Long

Public Sub Consolidate()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select files to process"
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook

        For File = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

            Filename = .SelectedItems.Item(File)

           If Right(Filename, 4) = ".csv" Then
    Set csvFiles = Workbooks.Open(Filename, 0, True)
    r = wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("AK:AK").EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").EntireColumn.Offset(0, 1)
    csvFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False 'close without saving
            End If


        Next File 'go to the next file and repeat the process

    End With

    Set wsMaster = Nothing
    Set csvFiles = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True

    End With

End Sub
```

**Edited new code from bruce wayne**

```
Option Explicit
Dim wsMaster As Workbook, csvFiles As Workbook
Dim Filename As String
Dim File As Integer
Dim r As Long

Public Sub Consolidate()

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        .Title = "Select files to process"
        .Show

        If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then Exit Sub

        Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook

Dim copyRng As Range, destRng As Range
Dim firstRow As Long
For File = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

    Filename = .SelectedItems.Item(File)

    If Right(Filename, 4) = ".csv" Then
        Set csvFiles = Workbooks.Open(Filename, 0, True)
        r = wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

        '' This is the main new part
        Set copyRng = csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("AK1:AK" & r)
        With wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1")
            firstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            Set destRng = .Range("A" & firstRow + 1).Offset(0, 1)
        End With
        copyRng.Copy destRng
        ''''''''''
        csvFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False    'close without saving
    End If
Next File

    End With

    Set wsMaster = Nothing
    Set csvFiles = Nothing

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to add the data at the bottom of the existing data in column A, or always paste in the next open column?

Comment: Sorry, add to the existing data in column A.

Comment: Wait, it's pasting into the master sheet, column A? Not column B? (the `Offset` to me looks like it's going to column B, no?  Also, you can't copy an entire column, then another entire column and paste that *below* another "entire column".  You'll want to tighten up your `Range("AK:AK")` to go from the first cell, assuming row 1, to the last used cell in that column.  I *think* you want to copy `...Range("AK1:AK" & r)`, correct?

Comment: @BruceWayne , sorry master, its going to column B. Yes you are also right about the range. I am copying AK:AK. aiya now it got more complex.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to find the last row of the source and of the master sheet. To do that you can adapt this:

```
EndRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A").Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

You can then use the EndRow integer like this to paste where you want. With the coordinates row = EndRow, column = 2 or B:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(EndRow, 2).Paste
```

or like this to copy what you want. With the copy range of A1 to EndRow A:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(EndRow, 1)).Copy
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing the code under `Set wsMaster = ActiveWorkbook` with this:

```
Dim copyRng As Range, destRng As Range
Dim firstRow As Long
For File = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count

    Filename = .SelectedItems.Item(File)

    If Right(Filename, 4) = ".csv" Then
        Set csvFiles = Workbooks.Open(Filename, 0, True)
        r = wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

        '' This is the main new part
        Set copyRng = csvFiles.Sheets(1).Range("AK1:AK" & r)
        With wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1")
            firstRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
            Set destRng = .Range("A" & firstRow + 1).Offset(0, 1)
        End With
        copyRng.Copy destRng
        ''''''''''
        csvFiles.Close SaveChanges:=False    'close without saving
    End If
Next File
' etc. etc.
```

This creates two ranges, and will copy/paste accordingly.  It should take your `AK1:AK#` row and add to column B of your `wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1")` worksheet.

Comment: do I have to replace anything in my code? Seems like I should take out the copy destination line.

Comment: it seems to be grabbing the header only now. I updated my question to reflect your change.

Comment: @Jonnyboi - Step through the code with `F8`.  When it sets `r`, what value does that have? Hover the mouse over it and it should say. I'm going to guess that's getting set as `1`? (You do mean that it's only grabbing the header cell to copy, right?)

Comment: r = 2.  So i did it with more files, it grabs the proper data, but the headers were in there for the first few files, which is weird.. these file has more then just the headers.

Comment: @Jonnyboi - You just want to *copy* column AK's data, correct? Try this instead: `r = wsMaster.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("AK" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` and see if that helps. Sometimes `UsedRange` doesn't get the range you're expecting.

Comment: gives me all headers lol, should I go range AK2:A for the copyrng part?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150024/discussion-between-brucewayne-and-jonnyboi).